# Understanding the use of local command in Randomization Check

Tags: loops, foreach, stata, local

I am trying to run a do-file for an RCT. The authors are using the `local` command.

They create a local macro taking the value 1. Based on that, they are creating missing values for the var variable. However, after that, I cannot understand why they are adding 1 to it. Moreover, why are the `numvar` and `numvarse` being used for mean and sd?

Any explanation would be really helpful.

The code:

```
*RANDOMIZATION CHECK

local numvar=1

foreach var in T1_Client_Age T1_Client_Married T1_HH_Size T1_Client_Literate T1_Client_Education T1_muslim ///
                    T1_Hindu_SC_Kat T1_rest3    T1_Log_HH_Income T1_Household_Business     ///
                    T1_Client_Wage_Salaried_2 T1_Client_Bus_PR_Employed_2 T1_Client_Housewife_2 {
                    
        replace `var'=. if miss_`var'==1
        
        local numvarse = `numvar' + 1
        
        replace varname="`var'" in `numvar' 

        *MEAN AND SD FOR CONTROL
        quietly: sum `var' if  Treated_All==0
        replace Control=r(mean) in `numvar' 
        replace Control=r(sd) in `numvarse'  
        
        *MEAN AND SD FOR TREATED
        quietly:sum `var' if  Treated_All==1 
        replace Treat=r(mean) in `numvar' 
        replace Treat=r(sd) in `numvarse'  
        
        *MEAN AND SD FOR TREATED WITH FRIEND
        quietly:sum `var' if  Treatment_Peer==1
        replace Treat_Peer=r(mean) in `numvar' 
        replace Treat_Peer=r(sd) in `numvarse'  
        
        *MEAN DIFFERENCES BETWEEN TREATED AND CONTROL
         xi:reg `var' Treated_All i.sewa_center*i.baseline i.t_month  , cluster(t_group) 
        replace Diff_Control_Treat=_b[Treated_All] in `numvar' 
        replace Diff_Control_Treat=_se[Treated_All] in `numvarse'  

        *MEAN DIFFERENCES BETWEEN TREATED ALONE AND WITH FRIEND
        xi:reg `var' Treated_All Treatment_Peer i.sewa_center*i.baseline i.t_month   , cluster(t_group) 
        replace Diff_Alone_Peer=_b[Treatment_Peer] in `numvar' 
        replace Diff_Alone_Peer=_se[Treatment_Peer] in `numvarse'  

        
    local numvar = `numvarse' + 1   

        }
```

Comment: The problem here appears to be need to understand `replace` ,,,, `in` ,,,,, as well as `local` macros (not considered variables in Stata, although they have some similarities with entitities called variables in several languages). If you are maintaining or revising others; code, a minimal basis would be the programming chapters in the {U] manuak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle can be understood by looking at just a few commands.

```
  local numvar=1

  foreach var in ...  {
                
    
    replace `var'=. if miss_`var'==1
    
    local numvarse = `numvar' + 1
    
    replace varname="`var'" in `numvar' 

    *MEAN AND SD FOR CONTROL
    quietly: sum `var' if  Treated_All==0
    replace Control=r(mean) in `numvar' 
    replace Control=r(sd) in `numvarse'  
    
    *MEAN AND SD FOR TREATED
    quietly:sum `var' if  Treated_All==1 
    replace Treat=r(mean) in `numvar' 
    replace Treat=r(sd) in `numvarse'  
    
    *MEAN AND SD FOR TREATED WITH FRIEND
    quietly:sum `var' if  Treatment_Peer==1
    replace Treat_Peer=r(mean) in `numvar' 
    replace Treat_Peer=r(sd) in `numvarse'  
    
    local numvar = `numvarse' + 1   

}
```

`numvar` is initialised to 1. Within the loop, `numvarse` is set to 1 more than `numvar`.

The code then puts results for each of a series of variables in observations `numvar` and `numvarse`, including the name of the variable AND its mean and SD for various groups.

The key is to focus on

```
  replace ... in ...
```

where the `in` qualifier specifies `replace` only in that observation.

Towards the end of the loop `numvar` is bumped yet again.

In short, results for the first variable named go in observations 1 and 2; for the second variable named go in observations 3 and 4; and so on.

Minimally, this process depends on

1. There being enough observations for this to be possible. I count 13 variables, so there must be at least 26 observations in the dataset, which seems overwhelmingly likely.
2. There being an understanding that the variables being written to are **not** aligned with any other variables.

Some might find #2 and even #1 poor ways of working. They would want results to be written to a new dataset or to a new `frame`.

The code is not state of the art: using `xi` with `xtreg` has been outdated practice since Stata 11 (2009), but still works for many purposes.

(Detail: The code overwrites values in variable X with missing if separately there is a variable `miss_`X indicating that  variable X is missing. I don't think any remote observers can explain that.)